# Calculus Optimization Word Problem. Where is the mistake?

Tags: calculus, optimization

A   microwaveable   cup-of-soup   package   needs   to   be   constructed   in   the   shape   of   cylinder   to   hold   350   cubic   centimeters   of   soup.   The   sides   and   bottom   of   the   container   will   be   made   of   styrofoam   costing   0.03   cents   per   square   centimeter.   The   top   will   be   made   of   glued   paper,   costing   0.08   cents   per   square   centimeter.   Find   the   dimensions   for   the   package   that   will   minimize   production   costs.

[image: Original problem, stated similarly to text above.]

[image: Answers from the website]

Context: I'm a tutor and the student asked me this question.  The student's website lists the answers as r = 3.12, h = 11.44 and minimum cost = 10.09, with no explanation given.

My work follows here.
| Cost | Volume |
| -- | -- |
| $$ Cost = 0.03 \pi r^2 + 0.08\pi r^2 +0.03\pi r h$$ | $$350 = V = \pi r^2 h$$ |
|  | $$h = \frac{350}{\pi r^2} $$ |
| $$C = 0.11 \pi r^2 + \frac{10.5}{r}$$ | |

My answers are r = 2.48 cm, h = 19.32 cm and minimum cost = 6.36 cents
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+%28.11pi+r%5E2+%2B+0.03*350+%2Fr%29

Comment: Hmmm, the preview of my question shows the table correctly. However, the public version of my question shows the table markup syntax instead of showing a table.  That gets over my head.  Feel free to fix it, and let me know what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of the side is $2\pi r h$, not $\pi r h$.

This makes the answer
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+%28.11pi+r%5E2+%2B2*+0.03*350+%2Fr%29

r= 3.12044->3.12, h= 11.441593->11.44, and the full cost is 10.09 as the website expected.

Comment: That's very true.